# Special characters can't be inserted into database

Tags: php, mysql, text, wordpress

Im new to php. Im trying to read a text file and insert line by line data to database. My problem is for Some special character insert query does not works 
For example `Côte` , `d.ä.` , `d.y.` , `DAB-sändare` these all are working. But cant insert `d'affaires`. If i remove `d'affaires` then the query will execute otherwise it will not insert any data to database. The php code i used to reaf and insert to database is

```
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("testdb");
    $query="INSERT INTO keywords (id, keyword) VALUES ";
    $handle = fopen("Ordlista.txt", "r");
    if ($handle) {
        $i=1;
        while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
            // process the line read.
           // echo $line.'<br>';

            if($i==1)
            {
            $query.=" ( NULL , '".$line."') ";
            $i++;
            }
            else {
                $query.=" ,( NULL , '".$line."') ";
            }

        }
        $query.=";";
     //   $qr=htmlspecialchars($query,ENT_QUOTES);
        echo $query;
        mysql_query($query);
    } else {
        echo 'error opening the file.';
        // error opening the file.
    } 
    fclose($handle);
```

**UPDATED** 
I have used this code while creating a plugin in wordpress then the special characters are inserting as '`?`'. In the previous code it was working file the code change i done is

```
mysql_query("TRUNCATE TABLE $table");
//    $structure = "INSERT INTO $table (`id`, `keyword`) VALUES (NULL, 'test1'), (NULL, 'test2');"; // Keywords for Testing
//    $wpdb->query($structure);
   //read text file & insert to database start
   $query="INSERT INTO $table (id, keyword) VALUES ";
   $fllocation=PLG_URL.'/Ordlista.txt';
    $handle = fopen($fllocation, "r");
    if ($handle) {
        $i=1;
        while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
            // process the line read.
            if($i==1)
            {
            $query.=" ( NULL , '".mysql_real_escape_string($line)."') ";
            $i++;
            }
            else {
                $query.=" ,( NULL , '".mysql_real_escape_string($line)."') ";
            }
        }
        $query.=";";
        $wpdb->query($query);
       // echo $query;
       // mysql_query($query);
    } else {
        echo 'error opening the file.';
        // error opening the file.
    } 
    fclose($handle);
```

Comment: try mysql_real_escape_string()

Comment: [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: After reading your update: What's the charset and collate of your table?

Comment: @Sal00m I have tried this $wpdb->set_charset('utf8'); before inserting but not working..

Comment: See my answer, it should work

Comment: @Sal00m Not working does i missed some thing? mysql_query("ALTER TABLE $table CHARACTER SET = utf8 , COLLATE = utf8_unicode_ci;");

Comment: Did you execute before your insert statement right?

Comment: yes executed before insert query..

Comment: @Sal00m Yes executed before Insert Query

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52267/discussion-between-salini-and-sal00m)

Comment: The solution for the updated Problem is $query.=" ( NULL , '".mysql_real_escape_string(utf8_encode($line))."') ";

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try mysql_real_escape_string();

```
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("testdb");
    $query="INSERT INTO keywords (id, keyword) VALUES ";
    $handle = fopen("Ordlista.txt", "r");
    if ($handle) {
        $i=1;
        while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
            // process the line read.
           // echo $line.'<br>';

            if($i==1)
            {
            $query.=" ( NULL , '".mysql_real_escape_string($line)."') ";
            $i++;
            }
            else {
                $query.=" ,( NULL , '".mysql_real_escape_string($line)."') ";
            }

        }
        $query.=";";
     //   $qr=htmlspecialchars($query,ENT_QUOTES);
        echo $query;
        mysql_query($query);
    } else {
        echo 'error opening the file.';
        // error opening the file.
    } 
    fclose($handle);
```

Comment: if your problem is solved then please don't forget to accept this question as answer :)

Answer (score 3):

The best solution would be to upgrade from `mysql_*` to PDO or `mysqli_*`, as these allow you to run prepared queries with parameters. But if you can't do that, you have to escape the data:

```
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        // process the line read.
       // echo $line.'<br>';
        $line = mysql_real_escape_string($line);

        if($i==1)
        {
        $query.=" ( NULL , '".$line."') ";
        $i++;
        }
        else {
            $query.=" ,( NULL , '".$line."') ";
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

First, don't use the *mysql* extension. It has been officially deprecated.

Second, use a prepared statement with parameters to avoid any problems with SQL injection.

Third, make sure you're using a compatible connection, table and column encoding / character set.

For example, using *mysqli*...

```
$con = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'testdb');
if ($con->connect_errno) {
    throw new Exception($con->connect_error, $con->connect_errno);
}
$con->set_charset('utf8');

$stmt = $con->prepare('INSERT INTO `keywords` (`keyword`) VALUES (?)');
if (!$stmt) {
    throw new Exception($con->error, $con->errno);
}
$stmt->bind_param('s', $keyword);

foreach (file('Ordlista.txt') as $keyword) {
    if (!$stmt->execute()) {
        throw new Exception($stmt->error, $stmt->errno);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for the example using mysqli instead of deprecated mysql_* functions

Answer (score 1):

After reading your update, i think the problem is with the collate and charset of your table, execute this:

```
ALTER TABLE `keywords` CHARACTER SET = utf8 , COLLATE = utf8_unicode_ci ;
```